# why I cannot select xdebug to be php debugger in my eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xdebug

I have installed php5-xdebug in my ubuntu 14.04. however, when I tried to change the default debugger 'zend debugger' to 'xdebug', I cannot select 'xdebug'. 
see my eclipse configuration: 
so what is wrong with my eclipse ? 
[image]

The result of `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Sanity check: did you restart computer / eclipse / web servers, reloaded all configs and so on?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk  yes. I restarted everything.

Comment: Do you see xdebug in phpinfo?

Comment: @DaveCoast nope, I did not see it. But I really installed it by 'sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug'

Comment: @tqjustc - it sounds like you installed xdebug but didn't tell php that you want to use your newly installed extension (xdebug). You need to edit php.ini. Here's a link for ubuntu - http://purencool.com/installing-xdebug-on-ubuntu. If you don't see xdebug in php.ini, eclipse won't either.

Comment: @DaveCoast  I followed the instructions you sent. I still cannot get it. In the installed debuggers, I can see that there are two debuggers over there: zend debugger, xdebug. But I cannot select xdebug as my active debugger

Answer (score 3):

From Debug window(where your screenshot is at), click '**PHP Servers...**'(orange link) and then '**Edit**'. Now you should see the **Debugger** dropdown menu where you can change it to XDebug.

Same for the CLI Debugger. click '**PHP Executables...**'(orange link) and then '**Edit**'. Now you should see the **PHP Debugger** dropdown menu where you can change it to XDebug.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I case somebody has a properly installed x-debug (check on command line with *php -m*). In newer versions of eclipse (mine is 4.4) choosing the debugger is connected to PHP server option. There you can choose default debugger, which is then displayed correctly.
**EDIT:**
To change click on the "PHP Servers" link in the screenshot above. Then click "new" at the right side, to add new server. Then a window should come up and you should be able to change debugger to xdebug when defining new server. Use that server then.

Comment: I attached the result of `php -m`. but the interface of Eclipse is still the same as I posted.

Comment: What about `phpinfo()`? I had a situation where I could see xdebug in output of `php -m`, but it was not in `phpinfo()`. If it is not there, check that xdebug.so is placed at the right place (mine is `/usr/lib64/php/modules`)